# R function to create a new variable in a data table converting YYYYMMDD to a real date

Tags: r, function, date, datetime-format

I wanted use lapply to build an utility that converts the date format as below described.
What should be fixed?

```
library(data.table)
testYYYYMMDD <- c(20200321, 20191231, 20230630)
test <- as.data.table(testYYYYMMDD)

ToDate <- function(Data, DateYYYYMMDD){
    if (any(is.na(Data[,DateYYYYMMDD]))){warning("Some dates are NA")}
    Data[, NewColumn := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
    YYYY <- trunc(x/10000,0)
    MM <- trunc(x/100,0)-YYYY*100 
    DD <- x-(YYYY*10000+MM*100)
    NewColumn <- as.Date((paste(YYYY, MM, DD, sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
    ), .SDcols = NewColumn]
  return(Data)}

ToDate(test, testYYYMMDD)
```

Comment: The way you convert numbers to dates is so redundant. Try `as.Date(as.character(testYYYYMMDD), "%Y%m%d")`

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply to convert the number strings to dates, you can use `parse_date_time` from the package `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
format(parse_date_time(testYYYYMMDD, orders = "%Y%m%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2020-03-21" "2019-12-31" "2023-06-30"
```